# How can I write a simple browser with cefpython3 on Windows XP

Tags: python, windows-xp, chromium-embedded

I 'd like to use cefpython3 create a simple brower, and on mac I use this code

```
from cefpython3 import cefpython as cef
import platform
import sys
def main():
    check_versions()
    sys.excepthook = cef.ExceptHook  # To shutdown all CEF processes on error
    cef.Initialize()
    cef.CreateBrowserSync(url="https://www.google.com/",
                          window_title="test")
    cef.MessageLoop()
    cef.Shutdown()
def check_versions():
    assert cef.__version__ >= "55.3", "CEF Python v55.3+ required to run this"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and how can I get the same output on XP (XP Only support cepython31.2),help me plz

Answer (score 0):

CEF Python v31 doesn't have a hello world example. You can see all examples available in cefpython31 branch here:

https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/tree/cefpython31/cefpython/cef3/windows/binaries_32bit

Take a look for example for the pywin32.py example, it only has a dependency on the pywin32 library which is of small size.